# Upload Excel Data to Google Sheets automatically

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets-api, vba7, excel-2021

Does anybody know how to upload Excel data automatically to my Google Sheets document by hitting a button (underlying VBA code within a Macro) and GoogleSheetsAPI?

I have everything like ClientID, Secret, SheetID but can't upload anything as I always get an error like sub or function not defined. Now I'm trying to find a whole code.

As stated above, I tried something like that:

```
Public Sub putThisSheet()
    Dim result As cjobject
    Set result = putStuffToSheets(getMySheetId(), ActiveSheet.NAME)
    If (Not result.child("success").value) Then
        MsgBox ("failed on sheets API " + result.child("response"))
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Function getMySheetId() As String'// make this into your own sheet id
    getMySheetId = "1V54F5b1e1bOcJXJ_McRkpyJ5Dx_ndGnjdiZpBeyA4L0"
End Function

Private Function sheetsOnceOff()
    
    getGoogled "sheets", , _
    "109xxxxxxxxxxieuu2q3.apps.googleusercontent.com", _
    "CVgxxxxxxxxxePfe"
    
End Function
```

Comment: What language does googlesheets use?

Comment: You do not need to code anything in googlesheets. It should be possible to connect the sheet via API to Excel (using VBA).

Comment: However, if you have the data as csv or similar then no need for Excel at all.

Comment: I get data from another source that doesn't work with csv. Thus to make the whole process automated I try to upload all the data from the excel sheet to Google drive automatically